# Creating a Measure that returns DISTINCT COUNT by Country and Brand in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table like below:

```
Country, Advertiser, Brand, Spend
C1,      A1,         B1,    10
C1,      A1,         B2,    5
C1,      A2,         B3,    0
C1,      A2,         B4,    20
C2,      A1,         B1,    8
C2,      A1,         B5,    7
C2,      A2,         B6,    4
C2,      A2,         B3,    3
C2,      A2,         B7,    2
C2,      A3,         B8,    9
```

I'd like to get the `DISTINCT COUNT` of Brands by Country, which is simply:

```
C1 => 4
C2 => 6
```

How do I create a measure in `Power BI` that I can embed in a table or a tree-map? I have already tried this:

```
Measure = COUNTX(DISTINCT(sourceTable),sourceTable[Brand])
```

which returns total Brand count (not `DISTINCT COUNT`) per Country...

I have also tried below and it didn't work:

```
DistinctBrandCount =
    CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(SampleDataForDashboard[Brand]),
        GROUPBY(SampleDataForDashboard, SampleDataForDashboard[Country]))
```

Comment: I believe just creating a measure like so:  Distinct Brtands := DISTINCTCOUNT(sourceTable[Brand]) and apply it to the country field should work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

StelioK is correct, you can just use a measure like this:

```
DistinctBrands = DISTINCTCOUNT(sourceTable[Brand])
```

When you put the measure into a table with `Country` on the rows, the filter context passed to the measure only includes the country for that row.

[image: Table]

If you want to keep all of your other columns as well, you can write you measure like this:

```
DistinctBrands = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(sourceTable[Brand]),
                     ALLEXCEPT(sourceTable, sourceTable[Country]))
```

This removes all filter context except for the `Country` and then calculates the distinct count.

[image]

Comment: it works! I swear when I tried `DISTINCTCOUNT` yesterday, it didn't work... I will post a follow-up question about how to make that number appear by default (not as a tooltip) in a Tree-map. Thank you for your help!